# is there a toggleSrc method in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Does jQuery have something like toggleSrc :-p ??

I want to change src of an image on slideToggling of a div.is there something like that give me the chance of not writing conditional statement to check the src of image to change to another src.
(I am not lazy !!!)

Comment: The easiest way to tell is open up your browsers console and run `$('selector').methodName;`

If it's there, it'll return a function, if not, it'll return undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in method for this, but you could make a plugin for it, for example:

```
$.fn.toggleSrc = function(onSuffix, offSuffix) {
  return this.attr("src", function(i, src) {
    return src.indexOf(onSuffix) != -1 ? src.replace(onSuffix, offSuffix)
                                       : src.replace(offSuffix, onSuffix);
  });
};
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
$("img").toggleSrc("_on", "_off");
```

...or a big safer:

```
$("img").toggleSrc("_on.jpg", "_off.jpg");
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fPuKb/). There are (as usual) 10 *other* ways to do this as well, this is just one example of how to do this and save you some code repetition.

Comment: dummyimage.com - that's handy :) I was thinking the same but putting the alternate image URL in a data attribute.

Comment: @sje397 - that also works, there's at least a dozen ways to approach this, it all depends on which works best for the site you're working on (e.g. is it a suffix? can it be a class with a background image? in which case `.toggleClass("onClass offClass")` would be even simpler :)